# pip install asteval fails on six dependency

Tags: python, pip

If I create a clean virtualenv, upgrade my pip version to 9.0.1 (most recent), and try:

```
$ pip install asteval
Collecting asteval
  Downloading asteval-0.9.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-nnWnaR/asteval/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import asteval
      File "asteval/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from .asteval import Interpreter
      File "asteval/asteval.py", line 18, in <module>
        import six
    ImportError: No module named six

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-nnWnaR/asteval/
```

Maybe I'm missing something, I thought pip should handle the dependencies?  I thought it used to.

The bypass is to separately `pip install six`, then asteval will install.  But I want to require asteval as an import requirement in my code, and I don't want to have to trace dependencies it might have and list those as requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

asteval is making a common mistake: importing itself into its setup.py.  You should file a bug against the project, asking them to stop doing that.

Comment: yeah, this was indeed a silly mistake in setup.py.  Now fixed with v 0.9.11.